# How to Move AWS Open search old indexes to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

I am using aws open search & have a domain & cluster which has old indexes
I want to copy or move ld data to S3 bucket how can we achieve this.

Note: Fine Grained Access control is not enabled in Security configuration

I tried following the instructions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html
but unable to go through